# AngularJS : Best way to use directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-local-storage

**Explanation:**

I created a `header` `directive` for my angular application. By using this directive we are loading `template` by using `templateUrl` property of attribute based on some conditions.

**HTML:**

```
<div header></div>
```

**directive:**

```
app.directive('header', ['LS', function(LS) {
'use strict';

var user = LS.getData() === 'true' ? true : false;
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: user ? 'withlogin-header.html' : 'withoutlogin-header.html',
    controller: ['$scope', 'LS', function ($scope,LS) {
      $scope.login = function() {  
      return LS.setData(true);
      }
      $scope.logout = function() {
      return LS.setData(false);
      }
    }]
  }
}]);
```

**withlogin-header.html:**

```
<div>
    User  is logged in !!!
    <input type="button" ng-click="logout()" value="Logout"/>
</div>
```

**withoutlogin-header.html:**

```
<div>
    Hey buddy, log in !!!
    <input type="button" ng-click="login()" value="Login"/>
  </div>
```

**Requirement :**

We have to display `different headers` based on the `user roles`.i.e if user was not login then we have to display normal header with `login button` and if user already login then we have to display different header with `logout button`.

**Challenge we are facing :**

`header` directive is not working properly. when we click on the `login button` from `withoutlogin-header.html` it not loading another template `withlogin-header.html` based on the defined condition in the `templateUrl` property of the directive.

I tried so far:

Plnkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/w7AyUjSNA1o5NJp6tD1p?p=preview

Comment: It is because your template has been loaded already with this directive and this directive is already loaded inside DOM, later this directive will not go through initialisation phase.

Comment: @AnkitPundhir, I totally agree with you but is there any way to fullfill the requirement.

Comment: Instead of use `templateUrl` you can use `ng-include` in template. Like `template:'<span ng-include=" user ? \'withlogin-header.html\' : \'withoutlogin-header.html\'"></span>'`

Comment: Is the `user` variable ever updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this plunker i have created an amazing `directive` for fetching `dynamic header` template from server.

I have made some little changes to your code as well.
Hope it will help you surely...

http://plnkr.co/edit/GWIozm?p=preview

Comment: upvote because it's working as per requirement. But, i have a question here. Is this a good way to use manual watchers because angular also have inbuild watchers that watch for directive or scope changes and perform actions against them.

Comment: Angular JS add watchers for inbuilt directives. For custom directive we have to add watchers manually. I think its a good way of doing so. I am in search of further optimised solution, will share if found one.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the templates into a single directive:

html:

```
<div ng-if="!isLoggedIn">
    Hey buddy, log in !!!
    <input type="button" ng-click="login()" value="Login"/>
</div>
<div ng-if="isLoggedIn">
    Hey buddy, log in !!!
    <input type="button" ng-click="login()" value="Login"/>
</div>
```

directive:

```
app.directive('header', function() {
  'use strict';
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'withlogin-header.html',
    controller: ['$scope', 'LS', function ($scope,LS) {
      $scope.isLoggedIn = false;
      $scope.login = function() {  
        LS.setData(true);
        $scope.isLoggedIn = LS.getData() === 'true';
      }
      $scope.logout = function() {
        LS.setData(false);
        $scope.isLoggedIn = LS.getData() === 'true';
      }
    }]
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** or if you want to stick to separate template files, you could use `ng-include` as @Stepan Kasyanenko mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation in that I display a certain list of URLS for anonymous users and a different list once the user is logged in.  I approached this solution by adding a $watch on the user's logged in property as well as the user's selected language at login (coding for multiple countries)

```
$scope.$watch(function () {
    return User.language;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal === undefined) {
        newVal = "english";
    }
    navBarCtrl.AnonymousUrls = [];
    navBarCtrl.AuthenticatedUrls = [];
    $http.get('http://localhost:#####/Urls/' + newVal)
        .success(function (data) {                
            navBarCtrl.sortAllUrlLists(data, navBarCtrl.AnonymousUrls, navBarCtrl.AuthenticatedUrls);
    });//end of http get
}, true);

$scope.$watch(function () {
    return User.isAuthenticated;
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {
    navBarCtrl.isUserAuthenticated = newVal;
}, true);
```

These two properties are set when the user logs in using the following

```
this.submit = function () {
    var data = angular.toJson(submitForm.credentials);
    $http.post("/submitLogin", data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            submitForm.user.isAuthenticated = true;
            submitForm.user.username = data.username;
            submitForm.user.location = data.location;
            submitForm.user.dsn = data.dsn;
            submitForm.user.language = data.language;
            $location.path(User.intededPath);                        
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            submitForm.user.isAuthenticated = false;
            alert("fail");
        }); // end of $http.post
} // end of submit
```

Finally in the view I have the following to display the correct list based on whether or not the user is logged in

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li ng-class="{'dropdown':urlList.length>1}" ng-show="!navBarCtrl.isUserAuthenticated" ng-repeat="urlList in navBarCtrl.AnonymousUrls">
             <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-if="urlList.length>1">{{urlList[0].Label}} </a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="urlList.length>1">
                 <li ng-repeat="url in urlList" ng-if="$index > 0">
                     <a href="{{url.Path}}">{{url.Label}}</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
             <a href="{{urlList[0].Path}}" ng-if="urlList.length==1">{{urlList[0].Label}}</a>
         </li>
         <li ng-class="{'dropdown':urlList.length>1}" ng-show="navBarCtrl.isUserAuthenticated" ng-repeat="urlList in navBarCtrl.AuthenticatedUrls">
             <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" ng-if="urlList.length>1">{{urlList[0].Label}}  <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-if="urlList.length>1">
                 <li ng-repeat="url in urlList" ng-if="$index > 0">
                     <a href="{{url.Path}}">{{url.Label}}</a>
                 </li>
             </ul>
             <a href="{{urlList[0].Path}}" ng-if="urlList.length==1">{{urlList[0].Label}}</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Hopefully that might give you an idea on how to get yours working.